# Why is this toggle() for animate() not working?

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I have this `toggle()` for the `animate()` method, so that on one click it will toggle the animation and all the inline styles and on the alternate click it will remove them and go back to the normal state. However, when I add the toggle code in, it doesn't work anymore (i.e it works without the toggle, but doesn't go back up again after the first click).

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $("ul li").each(function (index) {
        $("a").toggle(function () {
            $("ul li").animate({
                'top': ((index + 1) * 31) + 6 + "px",
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 0);
        }, function () {
            $("ul li").animate({
                'top': '0',
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 0);
        });
    });
});
```

I think I might be using the toggle wrong (I've read that the toggle should be used on the element that's clicked but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right) and also I'm not to sure about the `each()` function. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery? (.toggle no longer binds click events as of 1.9)

Comment: @KevinB I'm using 1.9.1...how else would I be able to achieve this then? :)

Comment: @TomOakley use migrate plugin for this with jQuery 1.9.1....:)

Comment: @TomOakley can you post/create a fiddle for this code. That would be more than useful.

Comment: I don't know what the intent of your code is. The each and the toggle both seem to be out of place.

Comment: Hold on I lie, I'm on 1.8.2. Still not working properly though, toggles the link (which I'm clicking) instead of the li.

Comment: Right, because in 1.8.2, using .toggle with two functions will bind click events, not toggle elements. You're still using .toggle wrong.

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Sure guys, sorry I didn't give a jsfiddle before. I thought I had some of the syntax wrong, but maybe it's deeper than that. Thanks to everyone helping me out :) Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/3fRwX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work for you. Just copy and paste this entire code in one html file and then check it out.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
ul li {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 1</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 2</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 3</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" t="0">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function () {
if($(this).attr("t")=="0"){
$(this).attr("t","1");
    $("ul li").each(function (index) {
        $(this).animate({
            'top': ((index + 1) * 31) + 6 + "px",
            'opacity': '1'
        }, "slow");
    });
    }else
    {
        $(this).attr("t","0");
        $("ul li").each(function (index) {
        $(this).animate({
            'top': "0px",
            'opacity': '0'
        }, "slow");
    });
    }
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While it does work, and that's awesome, it's a bit messy...I'm pretty sure it could be made easier and with less code than this. Thanks anyway! :) P.S - I hope you don't mind, but I cleaned up your code a little to make it more readable. Also updated the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6S3gz/1/ :)